# Git - remote repository only fetch

Tags: git, shell, command-line, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm learning Git, I understand the basics, but now I'm stuck.
What I'm trying to accomplish is:

- Is it possible that I create a repository where I add a remote repository which I only can fetch?

As example of a folder-structure:

- app / front
- app / admin

When I create a new repository, I want to download the complete folder structure, but when I push, I only want to push whats in the front-folder. The changes I do in the admin-folder, git cannot see these changes and will not push them to the server. That's what I want.

(Is it also possible to exclude some specific files in the front-folder from pushing?)

Which commands do I have to type in? Or where can I get some more info about this?
I'm also working with SourceTree, mayby there something already built in?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you need a git tutorial. The ones at codeschool.com are excellent

Comment: Thats an option, but first I'll try with the help of this site ;)

Comment: @KevinGorjan your question is a little unclear.  It looks like you still want to be able to push at least **some** files to your remote repo, would that be correct?  It's unusual to exclude changes to a file or folder that is already being tracked by Git.

Answer (score 0):

read about `.gitignore` to exclude files from being added to git / being shown in `git status`.

make the admin part a separate repository, put it in the general repository and ignore it there.

my personal recommendation for beginners is NOT to try out `submodule`s as they will confuse you.

Comment: Okay, at the moment, I'm working with .gitignore. Therefore I'm going to try out the git submodules. I'll just play with for a little while so I'll understand this.

Comment: `.gitignore` can be set to exclude the `admin` directory, but according to @KevinGorjan, it's already being tracked by Git in the remote repo.  To properly ignore the file, he'd have to untrack the folder in Git, i.e. delete it from Git.